# Weird Mesh/UV problem cant seem to fix it

Tags: blender, mesh, 3dsmax, uv-mapping, 3ds

I have a model of a Opel Blitz: Maultier and im facing a problem, the meshes or something seem to be duplicated or somehow bugging in a weird way. Quick clip: [Video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCf7n.jpg)

Same problem in 3ds Max 2020, if somebody wants the files i can provide them if needed.

i already tried to remove materials and i tried to see if i can do something with the meshes but no luck.. didn't find a way.

Comment: I think it's better to ask blender questions at https://blender.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Alright thanks F.NiX, i will ask there

Answer (score 0):

From the video, this seems like a Z-Fighting issue: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting

However, it is hard to know exactly what is the issue without looking at the model.
I could look more into it if you share the 3ds Max file.

Comment: You can download the file from here: [Download](https://www.mediafire.com/file/tdaymwl7so1h5st/Sample.fbx/file)

Comment: How is it looking? Found any solution?

Comment: looking into it, sorry for the delay

Comment: The problem seems to come from viewport clipping.
This video should show you how to fix this.  Let me know if you solved the issue :)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tbMMmH3WL80

Comment: This post explain pretty well the issue:
https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/8398/3ds-max-z-fighting-when-working-with-large-objects